# "Duplicate column name" error that shouldn't exist

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariasql

I'm trying to migrate a database from sqlite to mariaDB ( which I never worked with ) and I can't seem to get past this problem!

When I try to run this, I always get

```
"#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id_document'"
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  a.id_document AS id_document,
  id_user_associatedDoc,
  id_user_creator,
  stage,
  title,
  goldStandardAnnotationManual,
  count(content) AS answer_count
FROM
  (SELECT * 
  FROM Document join DocumentProject 
  ON Document.id_document = DocumentProject.id_document 
  WHERE DocumentProject.id_project = 2) a
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * 
  FROM Annotation 
  WHERE Annotation.id_project = 2) b 
  ON a.id_document = b.id_document
GROUP BY a.id_document;
```

I don't understand why I should be getting this error! Can you help?

Comment: This query is incorrect in multiple ways 1) `SELECT * 
    FROM Document join DocumentProject 
    ON Document.id_document = DocumentProject.id_document 
    WHERE DocumentProject.id_project = 2)` column id_document is present twice 2) GROUP BY does not match `SELECT` column list 3) subqueries are not mandatory

Comment: Select * isn't very useful since you are only using a subset of * and it's difficult to understand where most of your columns are coming from because they are not aliased.

Comment: Besides because the query has that much problems i advice you to provide table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`),  example data and expected results as text formatted data tables.. i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You can (and should) probably get rid of the 'derived' tables (subqueries) and simply have one `SELECT ... FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ... WHERE ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first subquery syntax returns two id_document column:

```sql
(SELECT *
 FROM Document
   join DocumentProject
   ON Document.id_document = DocumentProject.id_document
 WHERE DocumentProject.id_project = 2) a
```

A quick way to fix this:

```sql
SELECT
  a.id_doc /*Change this column as following*/ AS id_document,
  id_user_associatedDoc,
  id_user_creator,
  stage,
  title,
  goldStandardAnnotationManual,
  count(content) AS answer_count
FROM
  (SELECT *, Document.id_document as "id_doc" /*define the first id_document column as a different name*/
  FROM Document
    join DocumentProject 
    ON Document.id_document = DocumentProject.id_document 
  WHERE DocumentProject.id_project = 2) a
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * 
  FROM Annotation 
  WHERE Annotation.id_project = 2) b 
    ON a.id_document = b.id_document
GROUP BY a.id_document;
```

You can also pre-define which column you want to return inside the subquery as well. Example:

```sql
(SELECT Document.id_document, Document.column_2, Document.column_3
 FROM Document
   join DocumentProject
   ON Document.id_document = DocumentProject.id_document 
 WHERE DocumentProject.id_project = 2) a
```

That way, your outer query should select the a.id_document according to what you have pre-define inside the subquery and no need to change anything from the outer query.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your answer! I've been so busy I could only try it out now. Unfortunately, even after naming every possible id_document column I get the same error :(
I defined the column on the final query, and where you said "define the first id_document column as a different name", I defined also the second one.

Comment: I am very sorry, I was too busy with work I haven't check or update this post at all. tell me @user5646514 , you still have this problem?

Comment: Same for me with being busy. In the end I ended up rewriting the whole thing (it wasn't my query originally) with ids in everything that could be repeated and it worked! So I think you were right :) Thank you!